# Agda type-safe cast / coercion

Tags: agda

I found handy a function:

```
coerce : ∀ {ℓ} {A B : Set ℓ} → A ≡ B → A → B
coerce refl x = x
```

when defining functions with indexed types. In situations where indexes are not definitionally equal i,e, one have to use lemma, to show the types match.

```
zipVec : ∀ {a b n m } {A : Set a} {B : Set b} → Vec A n → Vec B m → Vec (A × B) (n ⊓ m)
zipVec [] _ = []
zipVec {n = n} _ [] = coerce (cong (Vec _) (0≡n⊓0 n)) []
zipVec (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys) = (x , y) ∷ zipVec xs ys
```

*Note*, yet this example is easy to rewrite so one don't need to coerce:

```
zipVec : ∀ {a b n m } {A : Set a} {B : Set b} → Vec A n → Vec B m → Vec (A × B) (n ⊓ m)
zipVec [] _ = []
zipVec (_ ∷ _) [] = []
zipVec (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys) = (x , y) ∷ zipVec xs ys
```

Sometimes pattern matching doesn't help though.

**The question:** But I wonder, whether something like that functions is already in `agda-stdlib`? And is there something like *hoogle* for Agda, or something like *SearchAbout*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is exactly your `coerce` function. However, it's a special case of a more general function - `subst` (the substitutive property of equality) from `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality`:

```
subst : ∀ {a p} {A : Set a} (P : A → Set p) {x y : A}
      → x ≡ y → P x → P y
subst P refl p = p
```

If you choose `P = id` (from `Data.Function`, or just write `λ x → x`), you get:

```
coerce : ∀ {ℓ} {A B : Set ℓ} → A ≡ B → A → B
coerce = subst id
```

---

By the way, the most likely reason you won't find this function predefined, is that Agda deals with `coerce`s like that through `rewrite`:

```
postulate
  n⊓0≡0 : ∀ n → n ⊓ 0 ≡ 0

zipVec : ∀ {a b n m} {A : Set a} {B : Set b}
       → Vec A n → Vec B m → Vec (A × B) (n ⊓ m)
zipVec [] _ = []
zipVec {n = n} _ [] rewrite n⊓0≡0 n = []
zipVec (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys) = (x , y) ∷ zipVec xs ys
```

This is a syntactic sugar for the more complicated:

```
zipVec {n = n} _ [] with n ⊓ 0 | n⊓0≡0 n
... | ._ | refl = []
```

If you are familiar with how `with` works, try to figure out how `rewrite` works; it's quite enlightening.

Comment: Nice! I realised that I wrote like `coerce (cong (Vec _) (0≡n⊓0 n)) []`, where I could do `subst (Vec _) (0≡n⊓0 n) []`. Much cleaner with `subst`.