# Agda: rewriting instead of explicit coercion in type definition?

Tags: agda, coercion, rewriting

When dealing with equalities on types in Agda, it is often necessary to coerce the inhabitants the types using a hand-made coercion like

```
coerce : ∀ {ℓ} {A B : Set ℓ} → A ≡ B → A → B
coerce refl x = x
```

It was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788547/agda-type-safe-cast-coercion) that explicit coercion of terms could sometimes be avoided using rewriting. I was wondering if this technique worked as well when defining types. So I wrote a little example where `f,g : A → Set` are two (extentionally) equal dependent types and a property `p : A → Set` where `p x` state that every element `y : f x` is equal to every element `z : g x`, that is `y ≡ z`. The last equality is ill-typed, as one can expect since `y : f x` and `z : g x` do not share the same type a priori, however I was hoping that rewriting could allow it. Something like:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate A : Set
postulate B : Set
postulate f : A → Set
postulate g : A → Set
postulate f≡g : ∀ {x} → (f x) ≡ (g x)

p : {x : A} → Set
p {x} rewrite f≡g {x} = (y : f x ) (z : g x) → y ≡ z
```

But the error is still there, even though the rewrite advice is accepted. So, is there a way to make Agda accept this definition without using an explicit coercion, like

```
p {x} = (y : f x ) (z : g x) → (coerce f≡g y) ≡ z
```

?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variation of your code that does what you want:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate
  A : Set
  f : A → Set
  g : A → Set
  f≡g : ∀ x → f x ≡ g x

p : (x : A) → Set
p x = ∀ y z → R y z
  where
    R : f x → g x → Set
    R fx gx rewrite f≡g x = fx ≡ gx
```

---

Why does this work when your version doesn't? `rewrite` affects two things: (a) the types of variables introduced in patterns left of the `rewrite`; (b) the goal type. If you look at your `rewrite`, when it takes effect, there is no `f x` to be found, so it does nothing. My `rewrite`, on the other hand, changes the type of `fx : f x` to `g x` because `fx` is introduced before the `rewrite`.

---

However, I would be surprised if this helped you much. In my experience, heterogeneous equality (i.e. equality between things of different types) remains annoying, regardless of what tricks you throw at it. For example, consider this variation of your idea, where we define a type `R` by rewriting:

```
R : ∀ {x} → f x → g x → Set
R {x} fx gx rewrite f≡g x = fx ≡ gx
```

`R` is a heterogenous relation which 'looks' reflexive. However, the closest we can come to stating reflexivity is

```
coerce : {A B : Set} → A ≡ B → A → B
coerce refl x = x

R-refl : ∀ {x} {fx : f x} → R fx (coerce (f≡g x) fx)
R-refl {x} rewrite f≡g x = refl
```

Without the `coerce`, `fx` would have the wrong type, and so we're back to the problem that we have these coercions polluting our types. This is not necessarily a deal breaker, but it complicates things. So, my advice is to avoid heterogeneous relations if possible.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! When you say that it "remains annoying", you mean that you still have to do coercions on the terms ?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an attempt to explain why heterogeneous relations remain troublesome regardless of how you define them. Hope that helps! Although I should mention that my expertise in this area is limited; it's really just a feeling that 'this sort of thing always gets me into trouble'.